# java_home not being set properly

Tags: java, installation, java-home

I have 2 Java installed on my machine. 1.5 and 1.6. For the project, I need 1.5. I have set all of my path variables to appropriate i.e.

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
<PATH_TO_1.5_JDK>
```

which is what i want .. but when i do

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03, mixed mode)
```

why java v 6 is being picked for `java -version` command ?

**UPDATED**
I have already checked the `%PATH%` variable and the only java version that appears in path is 1.5. I am referring to `SYSTEM VARIABLES` variable here and I am using Win7

Comment: have you check the PATH variable?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Did you `echo %PATH%` in the same terminal that reports java version 1.6?

Comment: Yes. I first ran `echo %JAVA_HOME%` which reported v 1.5 and then i ran the command `java -version` in the same terminal and it reported v 6

Answer (score 7):

Java 6 is picked because it comes first in you PATH environment variable. It has nothing to do with JAVA_HOME variable, until and unless you specify you PATH variable using JAVA_HOME variable

Setting a new USER variables PATH as JAVA_HOME\bin, will solve your problem

Comment: Yeah!!!
Same problem here, solved setting a new USER variable JAVA_HOME as <PATH_JDK>

Answer (score 3):

If you're running the `java` command on the command-line, the important environment variable is `%PATH%`: if the path to the JDK-1.6 *bin* directory precedes the path to the 1.5 *bin* directory on your path, then running `java` on the command line will use the 1.6 version.

The `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is used by various other programs to locate the JDK, such as ant, some IDEs, and third-party libraries.

If you're using a specific IDE for your project then you'll need to find out how it locates the JVM. If you'll be compiling on the command line, then adjust your `PATH` so that the 1.5 install precedes the 1.6 install, or use full paths to the compiler and VM.

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_HOME is differ from PATH where the java executes from.

Read this you will get clear idea

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that I fixed:

Path was not changing because user-specific `JAVA_HOME` was pointing to some wrong Java version.

Typing "edit environmental variables for your account" in run for Windows, I saw another `JAVA_HOME` in user variables. I removed it, and then the right Java version was used.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, none of the HotSpot Java commands use JAVA_HOME for anything:

Commands such as `java` and `javac` are located based on the PATH variable, on Windows, UNIX, Linux, and BSD-based operating systems such as MacOS.  Location of commands via the PATH is a typically command shell and/or OS function.

The JAVA_HOME variable is used by *some* 3rd-party tools such as Ant, Maven, Tomcat and so on to locate the Java installation to be used.  But other tools ignore JAVA_HOME and either use an application specific configuration mechanism (e.g. Eclipse), or some shell stuff to determine the installation location from (for example) the location of the `java` command found via the `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Java 7 and Java 8.

Solution: 
Remove from the PATH variable (System variables) the following entry :

```
c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\
```